# Replying to a wish you well text

Tags: sentence-choice

If someone wishes that you're doing well in your studies, can you reply the following?

> Thank you for wishing me well!

What could be some other informal replies?

Answer (score 1):

> Thank you!

is enough as the base answer. Forget "for wishing me well".

You can add another sentence like:

> - I will.
> - I will do my best.
> - I hope I will.

You may even add:

> - You are so nice!

As usual, any "Thank you!" comes with a smile ;)